# Dynamically assigning refs to dynamically created TextInput

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, react-ref

I am working on a form where the user can **dynamically add text fields** and move to newly added text fields by pressing next on the keyboard.

I am creating dynamic TextField by keeping the no of text fields in the state and increasing them by one when the user wants to add Text field.

I am assigning the ref corresponding to the **indexes** of the text field.
But When I'm trying to focus on next TextInput onSubmitEditing I am getting a error
**undefined is not a object this[`${idx + 1}_ref`].focus()**

```
class FieldCollection extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const {values} = props;

    this.state = {
      noOfFields: values || [1],
    };
  }

  addField = () =>
    this.setState(({noOfFields}) => {
      const _ = [...noOfFields];
      _.push(1);
      return {
        noOfFields: _,
      };
    });

  render() {
    const {noOfFields} = this.state;
    return (
      <View style={styles.section}>

        {noOfFields.map((_, idx) => (
          <View style={styles.fieldsConatainer}>
          <TextInput
            placeholder={'Email'}
            returnKeyType={'next'}
            .
            .
            .
            ref={input => {
              this[`${idx}_ref`] = input;
            }}
            onSubmitEditing={event => {
              this[`${idx + 1}_ref].focus(); // focusing on the next input
            }}                           // throws undefined error
          />
        </View>
        
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.addField}>
              .
              .
        </TouchableOpacity>
       
        ))}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Can anyone suggest a better way of achieving this.

Comment: See [this](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1899). They have plenty way of doing this

Answer (score 0):

You can use Legacy API: String Refs but not preferred

```
{noOfFields.map((_, idx) => (
          <View style={styles.fieldsConatainer}>
          <TextInput
            placeholder={'Email'}
            returnKeyType={'next'}
            .
            .
            .
            ref={`${idx}_ref`}
            onSubmitEditing={event => {
              this[`${idx + 1}_ref].focus(); // focusing on the next input
            }}                           // throws undefined error
          />
        </View>
        
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.addField}>
              .
              .
        </TouchableOpacity>
       
        ))}
```

you can access them through `this.refs`.

Reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html